# How do I call a partial view with List collection in a view

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

i want display a Slider within the webpage slider page is partial

```
   @Html.Partial("~/Views/slider/slider.cshtml", new List<Mvc_baker.Areas.admin.Models.slidShow>())
```

this code view slider

```
<div id="amazingslider-wrapper-1" style="float:left;  display:block;position:relative;max-width:605px;margin:5px 5px 60px;">
<div id="amazingslider-1" style=" display:block;position:relative;margin:0 auto;">

    @{
        string imageBase64 = "";
        string imageSrc = "";
    }
    @*@if (Model != null)*@


    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <ul class="amazingslider-slides" style="display:none;">
            <li>

                @*<img src="~/Content/Images/main/sliderengine/main2.png" alt="main2" />*@
                imageBase64 = Convert.ToBase64String(@item.FImage);
                imageSrc = string.Format("data:image/gif;base64,{0}", imageBase64);
                @if (imageSrc != "")
                {
                    <img src="@imageSrc" class="info" width="100" height="50" />
                }

            </li>
        </ul>

    }
```

but when trace code view The code inside the foreach  will not run 
iam think problem is 
new List()
when replace with this code i am see error

> Compiler Error Message: CS0118: 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' is a 'type' but is used like a 'variable

```
 @Html.Partial("~/Views/slider/slider.cshtml", new IEnumerable<Mvc_baker.Areas.admin.Models.slidShow>)
```

how sloved this problem

Answer (score 1):

If you are just wanting to get this to compile change it to this:

```
@Html.Partial("~/Views/slider/slider.cshtml", 
   new List<Mvc_baker.Areas.admin.Models.slidShow>())
```

This changes it to a `List` class which implements the `IEnumerable` interface.

I guess at a later point you will want to pass this in as a model property like this:

```
@Html.Partial("~/Views/slider/slider.cshtml", Model.SlidesToShow)
```

This would require you adding this property to your model:

```
public IEnumerable<Mvc_baker.Areas.admin.Models.slidShow> SlidesToShow { get; set; }
```

Then populating it from your controller and returning it to the view like this (assuming property of `FImage` is a string without seeing your model).

```
model.SlidesToShow = new List<Mvc_baker.Areas.admin.Models.slidShow>() 
 { 
       new slidShow { FImage = "123"} 
 };
return View(model);
```

Comment: i am  @Html.Partial("~/Views/slider/slider.cshtml", 
   new List<Mvc_baker.Areas.admin.Models.slidShow>()) in _Layout page dont know  Model.SlidesToShow

Comment: @amir1364 Just put an `@using System.Collections.Generic` at the top of your view to import the namespace.